Will inner transaction rollback if later the outer transaction hit rollback using BeginTransaction()?
I have 2 methods like this, Method1 call Method2 do some operations with Transaction using BeginTrasaction:
public void Method1(string connectionString)
{
      var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      var transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
      
      try
      {
           con.Open();
           Method2(connectionString);
           do sth that make errors bla bla...;
           transaction.Commit();
           con.Close();
      }
      catch
      {
           transaction.RollBack();
           con.Close();
      }
}

public void Method2(string connectionString)
{
      var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      var transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

      con.Open();
      do sth that dont make errors bla bla...;
      transaction.Commit();
      con.Close();
}

I wonder if Method2 success and Commit the Transaction, but then Method1 hit the error and RollBack, will Transaction in Method2 RollBack too?
Thank you!
I've tried this but the result is not clear enough for me, I still dont get it how the transaction work in this case, is it treated as 2 separated transaction or not?

@AluanHaddad thank you for replying. Can you explain more clearly about use 'using'? Is that mean I should use 'using var transaction = con.BeginTransaction();'? If it is then can you explain why should we do that because I think 'using' open a scope to use 'transaction' instance, but I dont see why it is necessary

No, in this scenario Method2 has been already committed and it's over , so it won't rollback . To do this you might make sure that both Method1 and Method2 are in the same context (currently they are in a separated context) Or you can use  TransactionScope .

Wrong. It's about the "code" do sth that make errors. The correct answer is that the explicit rollback isn't necessary at all (ignoring other possible improvements in the code).

@GertArnold Can you please  explain why is that?

Method2 opens a transaction within the outer transaction. The outer transaction rules. It that isn't committed it'll be rolled-back automatically when the transaction is closed (the exact timing of which, without exception catching, is left to the runtime, because they don't use  using).

@GertArnold Can you help me explain why without 'using' the transaction will be rolled back although it run through 'Commit()'? Thank you

With using it will also be rolled back, but then it'll be at the end of the using.

@GertArnold so that means Method2 will be rolled back when Method1 hit the errors even when Method2's transaction is committed?
